# Logitech G-HUB Lua - Toggle Aim Macro with Cancel

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

For context, I'm playing a game that only has the option to hold RMB to ADS - want to have it as a toggle.

I am trying to build a Lua macro on GHUB that will enable me to press RMB to ADS and then be able to cancel the ADS either by clicking RMB again OR pressing space bar OR pressing another mouse button.

So far I have the below which works fine but I can't work out how to build in the functionality to cancel the toggle when I press other mouse buttons and space etc..

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
 if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 2 then
  Toggle = not Toggle
  if Toggle then
   PressMouseButton(3)
  else
   ReleaseMouseButton(3)
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use space key because GHUB is only able to monitor state of mouse buttons on a Logitech mouse and special G-keys on a Logitech keyboard.
GHUB is unable to handle press/release events of usual keys (letters, digits) on your keyboard.
Here is how you can use mouse button 8 to turn ADS off:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
 if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 2 then
  Toggle = not Toggle
  if Toggle then
   PressMouseButton(3)
  else
   ReleaseMouseButton(3)
  end
 elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 8 and Toggle then
  Toggle = not Toggle
  ReleaseMouseButton(3)
 end
end
```

Comment: Bloody legend, works perfectly. Thanks so much - really appreciate it!